# SItecore Docker Up Fails - Unhealthy

Tags: docker, sitecore

I am running Docker successfully on my laptop - no issues.
Sometimes I get this error:

```
 ERROR: for traefik  Container "64e4a46ba760" is unhealthy.
 ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

To fix the error, I usually follow these steps

1. docker down
2. Quit docker
3. Clean my deploy folder
4. Start docker
5. docker up

And it works

I recently had to setup docker on another laptop and I consistently get the error

```
 ERROR: for traefik  Container "64e4a46ba760" is unhealthy.
 ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I followed all the above steps, but the error persists. In addition, I did the following

1. docker ps
2. got the container id
3. docker inspect
4. get the ip address
5. ipaddress/healthz/ready

I can see the error:

"InnerException": {
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.",
"ExceptionType": "System.FormatException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)"
}

Version:4.5.1
[image]

Has anyone else seen this and know why it's happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the things on this Sitecore StackExchange post? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26777/error-container-is-unhealthy